# how to update all rows based on specific date and group by two fields by a single mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have following mysql table:

```
===================================
id | uid | vid |    date    | num |
===================================
 1 |  1  |  1  | 2017-01-01 |     |
 2 |  1  |  1  | 2017-02-20 |     |
 3 |  2  |  1  | 2017-02-25 |     |
 4 |  1  |  2  | 2017-03-05 |     |
 5 |  1  |  1  | 2017-04-01 |     |
===================================
```

I have to update num column in such way that if the date is the earliest date for the same uid & vid, then the num column will be 1, otherwise it will be 2. So, after updating the database/table the table will be:

```
===================================
id | uid | vid |    date    | num |
===================================
 1 |  1  |  1  | 2017-01-01 |  1  |
 2 |  1  |  1  | 2017-02-20 |  2  |
 3 |  2  |  1  | 2017-02-25 |  1  |
 4 |  1  |  2  | 2017-03-05 |  1  |
 5 |  1  |  1  | 2017-04-01 |  2  |
===================================
```

As 2017-01-01 is the earliest date among id#1, id#2 & id#5 `[uid=1 & vid=1]`, so num is 1 for `id=1` and in case of id#2 & id#5, the `num` values are 2.

But although `uid=1` is for id#4 but `vid=2` in that case. So it will be `num=1` as `2017-03-05` is the earliest and only one date for id=4 uid & vid combination. In the same way, num is 1 for id#3 as uid & vid are different.

How can I create a single mysql query, so that it will update the `num` column automatically based on the uid, vid & date?

Comment: is the date always increasing with increasing id?

Answer (score 0):

```
update your_table t
left join (
    select 
        uid, vid, min(id) as id
    from your_table t 
    join (
        select uid, vid, min(date) as date
        from your_table
        group by uid, vid
    ) t2 using (uid, vid, date)
    group by uid, vid
) t2 on t.uid = t2.uid
    and t.vid = t2.vid
    and t.id = t2.id
set num = case when t2.id is null then 2 else 1 end;
```

Comment: No, date is not always increasing with increasing id. Date may be either with increasing id.

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid - Updated the answer.

Comment: this error is showing: `#1054 - Unknown column 'date' in 'from clause'`

Comment: @Abdullah use whatever the name of your date column is. You mentioned date in question and thats what I used

Comment: You ll have to modify your qiery accordingly.. Have you done that? What is sql you used?